# Replacing the $safeprojectname$ with the projectname not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

When we uninstall this Xamarin.Form app from android device we are getting following error message , it is not replacing the $safeprojectname$ with the projectname. Can somebody suggest how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: I'm also interested in this this topic. I want to know how `$safeprojectname` is handled... in my case, I noticed that it was displayed after the splashscreen as "$safeprojectname" (sic), which is an undesired behavior for me.

Comment: Have reported this in bugzilla https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42172

Answer (score 3):

This value $safeprojectname$ is located under AppName.Droid => Properties => AndroidManifest.xml. You can manually change it.

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="SilCoyGetInstance.SilCoyGetInstance">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="TheNameYouWant"></application>
</manifest>
```